# What to add to my build.gradle for google maps

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add google maps to my android application. On the developer website it says use this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

but when i put this in it will not sync properly.... please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you have the Google Repository installed in your SDK Manager. If not, then you cannot use any of the Play Services libraries.

Then, I would recommend that you use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87` instead of what you have. What you have will pull in *all* of Google Play Services, which is rather large. The `play-services-maps` artifact will just pull in the Google Maps piece.